# Pandas.Dataframe.merge v Linq Join

Tags: c#, pandas, python-2.7, linq, google-bigquery

Having to migrate some Python code which reads two views of a GA dump for a given time period, then merges them. Works fine. Finding that my C# hangs on the Join

**Python**

```
private_key_loc = <<key>>

sql = <<bigquery>>
impressions_all = pd.read_gbq(<<bigquery>>,private_key = private_key_loc)

 sql = <<bigquery2>>

 clicks_all = pd.read_gbq(sql, private_key = private_key_loc)

 ctr = pd.merge(impressions_all, clicks_all, 
 how = 'left', 
 left_on = ['fullvisitorID','visitNumber','hits_hitnumber','visit_date','spid_seen' ], 
 right_on = ['fullvisitorID','visitNumber','hits_hitNumber','visit_date','SPID_clicked'])
```

C#

```
    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("<<FILE>>");
var client = BigQueryClient.Create("<<ProjectId>>",credential);

string sql = $@"<BigQuery";

BigQueryResults impressions = client.ExecuteQuery(sql, 
                        null, new QueryOptions { UseLegacySql = true });

string sql = $@"<BigQuery2>>";


BigQueryResults clicks = client.ExecuteQuery(sql, 
                        null, new QueryOptions { UseLegacySql = true });


var ctr = from impression in impressions
    from click in clicks
    where impression["fullvisitorID"] == click["fullvisitorID"]
          && impression["visitNumber"] == click["visitNumber"]
          && impression["hits_hitnumber"] == click["hits_hitnumber"]
          && impression["visit_date"] == click["visit_date"]
          && impression["spid_seen"] == click["SPID_clicked"]
    select new {impression, click};

ctr = ctr.ToList();
```

The code hangs on the final line.

**EDIT:**

I have tried materializing both impressions and clicks by calling ToList() before the join. Doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Have you isolated the problem? Can we reproduce it?

Comment: The problem is that the linq expression hangs. The data is biggish, and private, so can't publish it.

Comment: That's why I commented. You should start with a small reproducible example. If the problem is related with your data then is a local issue and we cannot help you.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera I appreciate that, but it seems a fairly standard implemenation, and  the data is a standard Google Analytics data import into BigQuery.

Comment: I don't see why it should hang in that LINQ expression. What about `impressions`? Is that a big set? Can you materialize it first before joining with the data from `clicks`? Are you sure it "hangs" or is it just extremely slow?

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera impressions is biggish. 500k records. Clicks is much smaller, aorund 50k. I should have clarified 'hangs' - I just haven't waited long enough for it to complete - but waited around 20 minutes. The Python statement takes a minute or two

Comment: Without knowing about record sizes, I would try loading them locally first and then do some testing. Having said that, I think this question is too localized and not a good fit for SO unless you find an actual bug in your code.

Comment: Aren't these slightly different queries? Your pandas looks like a LEFT OUTER JOIN where your linq looks like an INNER JOIN, but depending on how linq is translating this to BigQuery syntax, might also be a CROSS JOIN: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#cross-join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using BigQuery [CROSS JOIN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#cross-join) can be written explicitly (see above) or implicitly using a comma to separate the from_items. You should try with a small data, in this way you could figure out how Linq is translating your query in an [INNER JOIN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#inner-join) or an a [CROSS JOIN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#cross-join).

If is the second option this explains why your code "hangs" since a [CROSS JOIN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#cross-join) is the [cartesian product](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_garmany_9_sql_cross_join.htm) of your tables which would be huge (500k * 50k = 250,00,000,000 rows!).

---